# lambda explanation on the parameters used

Tags: python, list, lambda

I would like to inquire about something rather simple which is about lambda parameters.

I understand how the function of lambda works but when it comes to this I got confused with which is which parameters.

Example:

```
from functools import reduce

# Simple example so that I could understand based on the explanation from experts
# here. You could modify as however you wish to explain it.
product = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, [1,2,3,4])
```

Here is a shorter version to compare it:

```
product = 0
for x in [1,2,3,4]:
    product = product + x
print(product)
```

Now, my question is `x` is the variable for the list or `y` is the variable for the list in the first example for lambda? And what is the default value for either `x` or `y` (judging either one of it belongs to product? since I did not initiate the initial value for it for the "lambda example" and only the second example I initialized.)

Comment: Note that `product = map(lambda x, y: x + y, [1,2,3,4])` does an error when trying to convert to list.

Comment: You appear to have confused [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) with [`functools.reduce()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce).  Also, you appear to have confused product with sum.

Comment: sorry, I wrote the wrong code. I was suppose to use reduce and I have changed it

Comment: The product can be a name for product price and not only to product which use for *

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `map()` in python takes in a list, and returns a list where each element has been modified according to some function.  You seem to want to take a list as input and get a number as a result, in which case neither `map()` nor lambda functions are particularly helpful, and a simple `for` loop is probably the best way to do this.

Comment: Yes, I actually refer to an example from this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reduce-in-python/.

Comment: Ah, I typed this before your edit.  x and y are initially set to the first and second elements in your list, and at each step x is replaced by the result of the previous operation, and y is replaced with the next element in the list: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce

Answer (score 1):

With:

```
product = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, [1, 2, 3, 4])
```

each time the lambda function is called, the `x` argument is the running total (or *accumulated* value) and `y` will be successive elements of the iterable `[1, 2, 3, 4]`.

Since you didn't specify the optional *initializer* parameter, the value of `x` will be set to the first element of the iterable (`1` in this case) and the first call to the `lambda` with start with the *second* element of the iterable—otherwise `x` would have been the value passed as the initializer and the first call would have passed the first argument of the iterable as the `y` parameter the first time.